# Linearly independent continuous functions in connected, compact, Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a connected, compact, Hausdorff space that has no isolated points. Given $n \in \mathbb{N}$, show that there are continuous functions $f_{k}: X \to [0,1]$, $k = 1, \cdots, n$, that are linearly independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X$ is not finite, obviously. So pick $F=\{p_1,\ldots,p_n\}$, $n$ distinct points from $X$. Define $g_i: F \to [0,1]$ by $f_i(p_j)=\delta_{ij}$. Let $f_i$ be the Tietze extensions of the $g_i$ from $F$ (closed) to $X$ (as $X$ is normal). It's easy to see that the $f_i$ are linearly independent (by evaluating on the $p_i$).

Comment: We have not discussed Tietze extensions yet. We have discussed though Urysohn Lemma and Urysohn Metrization Theorem (which came before in our reference), if that can help in answering the problem?

Comment: @Brenda Tietze is an easy consequence of Urysohn.

Comment: @Brenda You can also use Urysohn on $p_i$ and $F\setminus \{p_i\}$ sending the first to $1$ and the rest to $0$, etc.

Comment: I see, will look into it. Thank you!